# How to Search Specific Column In Each Worksheet of Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel document with over 50 worksheets all with a similar naming convention.
As this will be so unfriendly for users to navigate to, I wrote a VBA macro which creates a worksheet called summary with the list of all the worksheets hyperlinked in a tabular form with Sheet A B and C as the Column and Sheet 1 and 2 as rows.

Now I am trying to go through each row of a specific column in Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 and look for any reference to SheetB, SheetC and SheetD and for each reference found and I want to mark that creating a matrix.

I am not sure how to achieve this. Any assistance will be much appreciated.

I have managed to search Sheet 1 and 2 for any reference to SheetB as shown below but I am not sure how to update the corresponding cell in my summary sheet.

```
Function findWord(word As String, wSheet As String) As Boolean

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    LastRow = Worksheets(wSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
       If Worksheets(wSheet).Range("D" & i).Value = word Then
          findWord = True
          Exit Function
       End If
    Next i
End Function


For Each wsSheet In wbBook.Worksheets
    If (wsSheet.Name <> wsActive.Name) And (Left(wsSheet.Name, 4) <>   "fact") Then
    For i = 2 To lastColumn
         MsgBox wsSheet.Name
       If findWord(columnNames(counter2), wsSheet.Name) Then
          'Update summary sheet
       End If
       counter = counter2 + 1
    Next i

End If
Next wsSheet
```

Comment: It's not clear to me, what do you mean by *"I want to mark that "*. As for the searching for all occurences, you can use `Do while loop` with `Find` method inside of `For Each mySheet in worksheets`. But you'll have to present some of your trials and be more specific, where you have problems.

Comment: Thanks. When I said "I want to mark that", I meant I would like to add an X to that row. For example of say I found a string containing SheetA in with Sheet1 then, I would add an X to my summary sheet table.  At the end my summary table should look like nots and crosses (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result in "Summary sheet" you are looking for is similar to this :
[image: Table on Summary sheet]

Then you can use something like this (read the comments inside the code for explanations)

```
Sub MarkReferencesToSheets()

    Dim wsSummary As Worksheet 'sheet with summary table matrix
    Dim wsSheetRow As Worksheet 'sheets in which we will search references to other sheets
    Dim strSheetColumnName As String 'name of the reference we are looking for
    Dim intSheetRow As Integer 'for loop purposes
    Dim intSheetColumn As Integer 'for loop purposes

    Set wsSummary = Sheets("Summary")

    For intSheetRow = 2 To 3 'change to suit; headers for rows in summary sheet
        Set wsSheetRow = Worksheets(wsSummary.Cells(intSheetRow, 1).Value)
        For intSheetColumn = 2 To 4 'change to suit; headers for columns in summary sheet
            strSheetColumnName = wsSummary.Cells(1, intSheetColumn) 'name of sheet we are looking for
            If Not wsSheetRow.Columns(4).Find(strSheetColumnName) Is Nothing Then 'look only in column "D", or 4
                wsSummary.Cells(intSheetRow, intSheetColumn) = "X" ' if we found it, mark it
            Else
                'if you want something else in the cell when reference is not found, put it here
            End If
        Next intSheetColumn
    Next intSheetRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Branislav. That worked! And yes, that's what I was looking for.